# "ValueError: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes." When converting str to fernet key

Tags: python, encoding, cryptography, base64, fernet

I'm trying to convert a raw string password into a fernet key. This code doesn't work:

```
# Convert the string to bytes
key_bytes = self.PrintPassword.encode()

# Base64 encode the bytes
base64_encoded_key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(key_bytes)

# Create a Fernet key using the encoded bytes
fernet_key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(base64_encoded_key)

self. Fern = Fernet(fernet_key)
```

Comment: Have you checked that it's 32?

Comment: The password I'm converting is 7 characters but this will vary

Comment: Doesn't the error say that it needs to be 32?

Comment: I've tried just putting equal signs but it doesn't fix it

Comment: Checking if it has a length equal to 32 won't make it have length equal to 32. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I believe @Joe is right. please try my answer bellow, using it it converts your password to 32 bytes string hash and then creates fernet key based on that.

Comment: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#using-passwords-with-fernet